# JS WebSocket failed to connect to python socket, [the server says it's connected]

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, sockets, websocket

I am facing a problem with establishing WebSocket connection,
Here is my code:

```
let sock = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/');
sock.addEventListener('error', (event)=>{
    console.log(event);
})
sock.addEventListener("open", (event) => {
    sock.send(JSON.stringify({'name':'test'}));
    console.log('MESSAGE SENT');
});
sock.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    console.log("Message from server ", event.data);
});
```

the server side code:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("", 8080))
sock.listen()
(conn, addr) = sock.accept()
with conn:
    print(f"Connected by {addr}")
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        conn.sendall(data)
```

This is the message I get in the browser

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/' failed:
```

This is the message I get in the server

```
[08/May/2023 15:17:01] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 65052
Connected by ('127.0.0.1', 51661)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python Socket module and WebSockets are not the same thing. You can't connect them together. If you want to make a WebSocket server in Python, you can review the [`websockets`](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) library. You can connect to Python WebSocket server with WebSocket client. If you want a example project using this library, you can review the Pie Socket article, ["How To Build WebSocket Server And Client in Python"](https://www.piesocket.com/blog/python-websocket).